# how to pull/push metrics in cloudwatch using client golang

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, apache-kafka, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

I am writing Kafka(MSK) subscriber(consumer) using GO (golang) and want to push metrics like message consumed count, error count etc. into cloudwatch metrics.

Pushing data directly using AWS-SDK PutMetricData() methods is making the function slow.

Answer (score 0):

If you often publish individual metric data points that can slow you down. The solution proposed by AWS documentation is to use [statistical sets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/publishingMetrics.html#high-resolution-metrics):

> You can **aggregate your data before you publish to CloudWatch**. When you have multiple data points per minute, aggregating data minimizes the number of calls to put-metric-data.

This is true for any programming language, whether it is Go or Java. Slowness usually comes from calling the **external API** to frequently, not due to nature of the language.

Comment: Hey Marcin, That's true about calling a external api, but I am looking for something like actuator in java which help to collect metrics and push into cloudwatch.  Do we have any such client present for GOlang?

Comment: @KewalAgarwal I'm not aware of such a tool. This is not something that AWS SDK provides. You either would have to find some third party solution for that, or implement your own.